# Python:"name 'cd' is not defined"

Tags: python

well, this is the code:

```
def post_search(request):
    global cd,results,total_results
    form = SearchForm()
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            results = SearchQuerySet().models(Post).filter(content=cd['query']).load_all()
            # count total results
            total_results = results.count()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/search.html', {'form': form,
                                                     'cd': cd,
                                                     'results': results,
                                                     'total_results': total_results})
```

find the error blow:
`name 'cd' is not defined`

I defined 'cd' , how it comes out this error ？

Comment: You defined `cd` if `'query' in request.GET` and `form.is_valid()`. If.

Comment: So what should happen when `form._is_valid()` is *not true*? Or `'query' in request.GET`, for that matter. You have no cleaned data then, so what should be passed to the template in that case?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, add the else will go right

Answer (score 0):

The variable `cd` gets declared only if `query` parameter is available in GET requests, and if the form is valid.

To solve this, declare cd on top, to any default value. eg)

```
cd = {}
if 'query' in request.GET:
```

Now if cd is not reassigned, you will have an empty dict that will be passed as cleaned_data to the template